# Looping thru Nested Arrays?

Tags: ruby, loops, multidimensional-array

I've been given an assignment which asks me to loop through an array of arrays and make a new array with the smallest numbers of each array.

I have to loop, and we haven't learned the '.map' method yet.

Comment: Since this is a homework questions: what have you tried so far to finish you assignment? maybe you can start with creating some sample data? And which sytnax/method would you use instead of `.map`

Comment: _I have to loop_ - ok, but what is the question? Or you just delegating your assignment to us?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use min

```
result = []
arr_of_arr.each do |arr|
  result << arr.min
end
```

otherwise

```
result = []
arr_of_arr.each do |arr|
  min = arr[0]
  arr.each do |elem|
    min = elem if elem < min
  end
  result << min
end
```

with map and min

```
arr_of_arr.map(&:min)
```